# Как отсортировать по минимальному id?

Tags: сортировка, mysql

Приветствую всех. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не правильно делаю.

```
SELECT 
  cabinet.name_test,
  MIN(answers.id),
  a1.answer_id as answer_id, 
  a2.answer_id as answer_id2
FROM cabinet
  JOIN answers a1 ON a1.test_id = cabinet.test_id 
    AND a1.user_id = '184918649' AND a1.friend_id = '353281'
  LEFT JOIN answers a2 ON a2.test_id = cabinet.test_id
    AND a2.user_id = '353281'
ORDER BY answers.id
```

Мне нужно отсортировать ответы пользователей по минимальному полю id.

Comment: Так понимаю, выводит одну запись. Подробнее объясните.

Comment: Он выводит ошибку #1054 - Unknown column 'answers.id' in 'field list'. Неопределенный столбец. Почему так пишет? У меня в таблице answers столбец id самый первый.

Comment: Если код изменили, то возможно дело в обратных кавычках.

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY answers.id DESC
```

не понятно что требуется

Comment: Он выводит ошибку #1054 - Unknown column 'answers.id' in 'field list'. Неопределенный столбец. Почему так пишет? У меня в таблице answers столбец id самый первый.

Answer (score 2):

У вас нету таблицы `answers` в выборке `FROM`. Вы эту таблицу переопределили алиасами `a1` и `a2`. Вот из них и выбирайте, например:

> SELECT ...
>
> MIN(a1.id),
>
> ...
>
> ORDER BY a1.id DESC

В добавок, когда Вы используете такие функции как MIN, MAX, COUNT и пр., должна быть дополнительная группировка GROUP BY, а у Вас ее нет